# Click stats for ads are wrong

Tags: bug, community-promotion-ads

The [stats](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5602) page for community ads has a bug in the way Clicks per day is calculated.

Clicks per day is using the number of days since the ad was first posted to meta, not from when the ad 'went live', leading to skewed statistics.

Comment: I noticed this too, now that I think about it.  I just didn't notice it enough to notice that it was a bug.

Comment: An ad can automatically phase in and out if its downvoted and then upvoted again. So that needs to be considered too.